# Is it safe to use selectors different then IDs in web testing?

Tags: angular, testing, cypress, playwright

I worked with **cypress** for few months and I get used to work with `data-auto-id` which is basically unique selector in my understanding.

```
<button data-auto-id="my-nice-button">
```

and then i can select it in cypress
`cy.get([data-auto-id='my-nice-button']...`

Now i tried **playwright** but selecting by text or stuff like this seems pretty unsafe for me.
Example from their website:

```
await page.locator('article:has-text("Playwright")').click();
```

What is considered safe approach? Should I use IDs in playwright or can I jump into CSS, text and other selectors? Please note that I have no real world experience so I don't know what's considered best practice. This question is not opinion based its more like is it safe or no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily for us, Playwright was many different [selector engines](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors). You can pick the one that suits better for your scenario.
Playwright also describes a good [set of best practices](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#best-practices). For instance:

- Attributes like text content, input placeholder, accessibility roles, and labels are user-facing attributes that change rarely. These attributes are not impacted by DOM structure changes.
- When user-facing attributes change frequently, it is recommended to use explicit test ids, like data-test-id. These data-* attributes are supported by the CSS and id selectors.
- And, XPath and CSS can be tied to the DOM structure or implementation. These selectors can break when the DOM structure changes.

If your team consistently uses `data-` attributes, you can keep using them.

Comment: sounds reasonable thank you :)